# Random numbers seeded by time don't change

Tags: c, random, time, random-seed

To generate random numbers between 0 and 1, I have written the following but of code:

```
 double random_0_to_1(){
    srand (time(NULL));
    random();
    return (double)random() / (double)RAND_MAX;
}

int main(){

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
        double temp = random_0_to_1();
        printf("%f\n", temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result that is generated however is always the same, no matter how many times I call it. The same numbers are always generated. I have tried a lot of different ways, but can't seem to find anything that works. Is there a way to generate random numbers that are different every time I call `random_0_to_1`?

Comment: There is a useless call to random in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three bugs in your code:

1. You're calling `srand` more than once. You should only call `srand` once, at the beginning of `main`.
2. You're initializing the RNG with `srand`, but then you're calling `random`, which uses a different, unrelated RNG. You should be calling `rand`.
3. You didn't include the necessary headers, `<stdlib.h>`, `<time.h>` and `<stdio.h>`, so your code has undefined behavior.

Comment: I see, in the meantime I tried to include the 'srand' in my 'main', but it didn't work. I had read somewhere that calling 'random' would produce a better result, but that doesn't seem to be the case, since I now get different numbers every time I call my main. Thank you!

Comment: @VincentVD If you want to use `random`, you need to seed with `srandom`.